# How do I bind listbox selected item to textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm having trouble linking a selected item in a listbox to display in a textbox. I've tried using onselectedindexchanged event in the listbox, but that didn't seem to work. The values in the textbox are retrieved using LINQ from an XML file. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with getting selected items to display in the textbox. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it makes a post back (when the index is changed), you can use OnSelectedIndexChanged in the server side to assign the selected value to the TextBox, else, if it does not, you should do that in the client side using Javascript.

Comment: you'll need to figure out the html tag of the items and then loop through it